# Simple .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I've looked online and couldn't find exactly what I was looking.  I tried to combine two different tutorials together but still nothing.

I need an .htaccess rule that changes:

```
game.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

to

```
/game/$1/$2.html
```

I've gotten it to work with one word as $2 but if there is a space, everything crashed.  My current code is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^game/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    game.php?id=$1&title=$2
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your wrote the opposite of what you are asking for. Currently your rewrite will rewrite

/game/$1/$2.html to game.php?id=$1&title=$2

```
RewriteRule  ^game/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /game.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

if you are wanting the other way like you asked it'd look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*?)&title=(.*?)$
RewriteRule ^game.php$ /game/%1/%2.html? [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only about spaces try adding "\s" to square brackets:

```
RewriteRule ^game/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\s]+)/?$ game.php?id=$1&title=$2
```